# Unable to use lua inside a `.vim` file

Tags: neovim, lua

I am using a nightly build of nvim, and I am trying to use `neovim/nvim-lspconfig`. I have followed to doc and setup the language server, but nvim throws error and reports that it is unable to process it.

The error is coming from the lua part. When I comment out it everything works as normal. Here is my code:

```
Plug 'neovim/nvim-lspconfig'
Plug 'nvim-lua/completion-nvim'

:lua << EOF
    require'lspconfig'.tsserver.setup{}
EOF
```

What have I done wrong? I have checked the doc again but I cannot find the error.

**Update**

This is the error message. Why is `lspconfig` not found? I have already `:PlugInstall`ed.

```
E5108: Error executing lua [string ":lua"]:1: module 'lspconfig' not found:
        no field package.preload['lspconfig']
        no file './lspconfig.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/Cellar/luajit-openresty/20201229_1/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta3/lspconfig.lua'

        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lspconfig.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lspconfig/init.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/Cellar/luajit-openresty/20201229_1/share/lua/5.1/lspconfig.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/Cellar/luajit-openresty/20201229_1/share/lua/5.1/lspconfig/init.lua'
        no file './lspconfig.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/lspconfig.so'
        no file '/usr/local/Cellar/luajit-openresty/20201229_1/lib/lua/5.1/lspconfig.so'
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to load the plugins, you have to wrap your `Plug` part with `call plug#begin(<path>)` and `call plug#end()`. So it should look like this for example:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'neovim/nvim-lspconfig'
Plug 'nvim-lua/completion-nvim'
call plug#end()

lua require('lspconfig').tsserver.setup{}
```

Comment: This answer fixed it for me!

Comment: Glad to hear this :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was fixed for me by ensuring `lua << EOF` and `EOF` were at the very beginning of their line. If there is even a tab or one space it breaks for me.